# How to create a complete C# program that will compute the salary with monthly bonus of employee

Tags: c#, debugging

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FNUV.jpg)

```
using System;
class Cris3 {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        String Name;
        double Salary, bonus, bonus1;
        
        Console.Write("Please Input Employee Name: ")
        Name = (Console.ReadLine());
        
        Console.WriteLine("Please Input Salary: ");
        Salary = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        

        if (Salary < 15000 && Salary >= 0)
        {
            bonus = Salary * 0.25;
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " +Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Bonus: " +bonus);
        }

        else if (Salary >= 15000 && Salary >= 0)
        {
            bonus1 = Salary + 5500;
            
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " +Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Bonus: " +bonus1);
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("INVALID DATA! PLEASE TRY AGAIN!");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This is the code I've been working for 2 days. Every time I try to run the code,the IDE always shows "Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings" but the IDE doesn't say what line or what's the error at all. Please help me.

Comment: Post the error *as text*, not an unreadable image. Images can't be copied, googled, compiled or tested. Errors appear both in the error window and the build output window

Comment: When I try this code I get `Compilation error (line 12, col 54): ; expected` and Visual Studio highlights the line `Console.Write("Please Input Employee Name: ")`. The final semicolon is missing

Comment: yeah this line:
Console.Write("Please Input Employee Name: ")

need to end in a semicolon like the other ones

Comment: Add a semi-colon behind `Console.Write("Please Input Employee Name: ")`

Answer (score 2):

So you are missing a semicolon at the end of this line

```
Console.Write("Please Input Employee Name: ")
```

If you add it, then the rest compiles OK.

FYI:  You can also use a website such as https://dotnetfiddle.net/, where you can post you code and run it.  This would also show you where the error is.